# Grant Cloudformation permissions to only resources that are part of the stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

At my company, our CI/CD pipleline can *only* connect to AWS via an assumed IAM role. I'm trying to lock down this role so that it can only update resources that are part of the stack, to avoid mistakenly changing a resource that is managed by another team.

I am running into a bit of a chicken or the egg scenario here. It seems that in order to create a role that restricts access to just the resources created by my stack, I need the IDs of those resources, which means the stack needs to have been created. I could run the stack with admin permissions once, then extract the resource IDs, and then put it into CI/CD, but that seems to defeat the purpose.

My ideal solution would be to be able to create a set of permissions that allow CloudFormation to create a fixed set of Resource Types, and then grant additional permissions to only those resources that were created as part of the stack. Is this possible? Or is there a different philosophy for how to manage the permissions for CI/CD?

Comment: Some IAM actions allow limitation based on tags. As a partial solution, maybe you can limit some of it based on the CloudFormation tag of the stack name?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I've tried with permissions boundaries but that failed as described in the following question I just asked:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423838/why-is-my-tag-based-permissions-boundary-not-allowing-access-to-my-cloudformatio

Answer (score 0):

What has me confused is how you want to "lock down" the resource to a particular stack. Anyway, try this:

Have a role that only have Create* permissions (You prob need Describe* too). This role is used to create new stacks and so it's not possible for it to meddle with resources already created.

In your CloudFormation template, create an IAM role that has Update* / Delete* permission to your resource. Call into this role when you want to modify the stack. Maybe give it a name of !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-CfnRole.

You'll also need to give it a deletion policy of retain and delete it manually after the stack is cleaned up.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html. Otherwise, when you call that role to delete a stack, you'll run into permission denied error as the role will almost certainly be the first resource to be deleted.

?? Does that work for you