# Why is my tag-based permissions boundary not allowing access to my CloudFormation stack's resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have created a role whose purpose is to hold the minimal privileges required to create, modify and delete one specific CloudFormation stack. I have to grant privileges to the role that allow it to perform a wide range of actions. Ideally, I would restrict which resources those actions can be performed on, however, since the resources don't exist yet when I create the stack, I can't. Even if I were to have a role for the update and deletion tasks, it would be far too laborious to write the policy and then this wouldn't work for resources that are replaced in updates. So I'm forced into creating an unnecessarily powerful role.

I have been trying to reduce this problem using a permissions boundary. According to [AWS's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html):

> An entity's permissions boundary allows it to perform only the actions that are allowed by both its identity-based policies and its permissions boundaries.

I also found that it's possible to use resource tags in policy conditions and hoped I could use the `aws:cloudformation:stack-name` tag that is added automatically by CloudFormation to all a stack's resources to act as the permissions boundary. Here's what I tried:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name": [
                        "my-stack-name"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Alas, this does not work. When I tried to delete an existing stack with name `my-stack-name`, deletion of the stack's resources failed with a message saying that "no permissions boundary allowed" the action. When I edited the permissions boundary policy to remove the condition, I was then able to delete the stack proving that the condition is the problem.

One potential flaw with this approach that did occur to me was that not all resources even support tagging so the permissions boundary would block access to them. For the failures I saw, though, the resources in question did have the tag.

Did I overlook some small detail that could make this approach work or is it fundamentally doomed in some way? What other options are there for reducing the power of roles created for passing to CloudFormation?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a mini breakthrough with this by changing the permissions boundary to:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name": "my-stack-name"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The key difference is using `StringEqualIfExists` in place of `StringEquals`.

I think this still leaves the role with enough permission to perform the wide range of actions on any resource that isn't tagged with `aws:ResourceTag/aws:cloudformation:stack-name` so it's not perfect but it's better than before. Also, the role's trust boundary determines that it can only be passed to CloudFormation so, overall, I'm feeling this is an effective approach.

Comment: Since I haven't truly answered the original question as I posed it, I won't yet mark this as accepted in case someone with greater insight into what's going on can add a more authoritative answer.